# External link routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, path, routes

Simple enough. When were making a typical restful rails app we would keep all routes inside of our applicaiton. Very rarely would a path link to an external path. But if we were to do it, I'm wondering what the best way is.

A typical matching of home

```
match "home"=>"appcontroller#home"
```

If we were matching an external url to a variable of path. We might do something like the below?

## First method

Routes.rb

```
match "external"=>"http:/www.google.ie"
```

Then in our html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Google', external_path %>
```

Note this is not actually a legal way of doing things but something similar may exist. It seems very close to the current way of defining paths in rails but with an external landing.

## Second method

Something that I've seen done elsewhere is to create a global variable for the external URL and use it in the link. EG.
in environment.rb or production.rb or whatever

```
@ext_path="http:/www.google.ie"
```

Then in our html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Google', @ext_path %>
```

---

So to recap. Whats the best way to use external URLS in rails. Paths? Variables? Other?
Any input appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have kept external links only in views. Because this links are not related to the any kind of logic of the application, and it's just an UI elements.

So, this way seems to me the best:

```
<%= link_to 'Google', "http://google.ie" %>
```

If you need to use this element many times, maybe it makes sense to bring this code into the helper, for example:

```
def search_engine_link
  link_to 'Google', "http://google.ie"
end
```

And I really think that is's not very good place to introduce a more complex logic.

Comment: I'd tend to agree, but there was an implied "per-environment" requirement in the OP's question, AFAICT.

Comment: It was more so to keep it dry. In the case where you have the same URL popping up all over the place which didn't belong to the application itself

Comment: The application helper. Not a bad choice but I'd use it sparingly

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use application-wide helpers wrapped around constants.

Helpers because I'd rather not see constants in templates, constants for environment-specific values.

I might use a hash to store the URLs: this keeps them more-tightly-coupled, and would allow environment-wide defaults, overriding per-environment as necessary.

The helpers could take symbols, or be generated from the hash keys, to generate `xxx_path` methods as happens with routes in `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself needing to do this because I had a link to an external site which I intended to make local in future.

In Rails 4 you can add this to `config/routes.rb`:

```
get '/contact', 
      to: redirect('http://www.example.com/contact.php'), 
      as: 'contact_us'
```

Which at the price of an extra redirect, lets you write:

```
<%= link_to "Contact us", contact_us_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

### 301-redirects

A note about use of   `redirect(...)` in the routes file. `Redirect` generates a 301-redirect, which is a specific thing, Google describes it as...

> If you need to change the URL of a page as it is shown in search
>   engine results, we recommend that you use a server-side 301 redirect.
>   This is the best way to ensure that users and search engines are
>   directed to the correct page. The 301 status code means that a page
>   has permanently moved to a new location.

So, using a 301-redirect in your routes for links to external websites may work, which it does, but the status information that is carried with that redirect is not correct.

If you've moved pages in your web app and want to tell the Google index (and everyone else) about it, then by all means use the `redirect()` to assure Google updates the index, but it's not optimal to use for standard external links out of your web app.